How can I refresh components on a record page via a lightning web component?
Disclaimer: I'm not a developer and I'm very new to working with salesforce and lwc.
https://imgur.com/a/aeAqBmb
I have a lightning:path component tied to an opportunity's stage. Clicking a stage in the path launches a screen flow as a modal. When using it to update an opportunity's stage, a manual reload is required to update the data on the record page. When updating a record through it's detail page, all components on the page refresh to reflect the changes. I am trying to do the same when (event.detail.status === 'FINISHED'), but I'm not having much luck.
Aura markup:
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pathStep" type="String"/>
    <c:salesPathStatus_Launcher recordId ="{!v.recordId}" aura:id="pathModal"></c:salesPathStatus_Launcher> 
    <lightning:path aura:id="picklistPath" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        variant="linear"
        hideUpdateButton="true"
        onselect="{!c.handleSelect}">
    </lightning:path>
</aura:component>

Aura controller:
   ({
   handleSelect : function (component, event, helper) {
    var stepName = event.getParam("detail").value;
    let pathModal = component.find('pathModal');
       
       
    switch (stepName) {
 case "Undecided":
           pathModal.undecidedFlow();
   break;
 case "Accepted":
           pathModal.acceptedFlow();
   break;
 case "Submitted":
           pathModal.submittedFlow();
   break;
 case "Negotiating":
           pathModal.negotiatingFlow();
   break;
 case "Closed":
           pathModal.closedFlow();
   break;
       }       
   }
})

Modal Launcher LWC js:
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import stage_Change_Modal from "c/stage_Change_Modal";

export default class salesPathStatus_Launcher extends LightningElement {


   /* STANDARD ATTRIBUTES */
   @api recordId;

   /* FLOW ATTRIBUTES */
   flowName;
   inputVariables;
   flowFinish = 'NONE';
   size = 'small';
   flowLabel = '';
   showFooter = false;
   showHeader = false;
   flowDescription;
   disableClose = false;
   autoRefresh = false;

   /* FLOW TYPES & ATTRIBUTES */
 
   //Undecided
   @api undecidedFlow(){
       this.size = 'small';
       this.flowName = 'Opporutunity_Sales_Undecided';
       this.flowLabel = 'Undecided';
       this.showHeader = false;
       this.showFooter = false;
       this.flowDescription = 'Test Flow';
       this.inputVariables = [{
           name: 'recordId',
           type: 'String',
           value: this.recordId
       }];
       this.flowFinish = 'STOP';
       this.handleFlowModal();
   }
   //Accepted
 @api acceptedFlow(){
       this.size = 'small';
       this.flowName = 'Opportunity_Sales_Accepted';
       this.flowLabel = 'Accepted';
       this.showHeader = false;
       this.showFooter = false;
       this.flowDescription = 'Test Flow';
       this.inputVariables = [{
           name: 'recordId',
           type: 'String',
           value: this.recordId
       }];
       this.flowFinish = 'STOP';
       this.handleFlowModal();
   }

   //Submitted
   @api submittedFlow(){
       this.size = 'small';
       this.flowName = 'Opportunity_Sales_Submitted';
       this.flowLabel = 'Submitted';
       this.showHeader = false;
       this.showFooter = false;
       this.flowDescription = 'Test Flow';
       this.inputVariables = [{
           name: 'recordId',
           type: 'String',
           value: this.recordId
       }];
       this.flowFinish = 'STOP';
       this.handleFlowModal();
   }
       //Negotiating
 @api negotiatingFlow(){
   this.size = 'small';
   this.flowName = 'Opportunity_Sales_Negotiating';
   this.flowLabel = 'Negotiating';
   this.showHeader = false;
   this.showFooter = false;
   this.flowDescription = 'Test Flow';
   this.inputVariables = [{
       name: 'recordId',
       type: 'String',
       value: this.recordId
   }];
   this.flowFinish = 'STOP';
   this.handleFlowModal();
}    

   //Closed
   @api closedFlow(){
       this.size = 'small';
       this.flowName = 'Opportunity_Sales_Closed';
       this.flowLabel = 'Closed';
       this.showHeader = false;
       this.showFooter = false;
       this.flowDescription = 'Test Flow';
       this.inputVariables = [{
           name: 'recordId',
           type: 'String',
           value: this.recordId
       }];
       this.flowFinish = 'STOP';
       this.handleFlowModal();
   }

   /* FLOW MODAL OPENING */

   async handleFlowModal() {
       this.result = await stage_Change_Modal.open({
           size: this.size,
           flowName: this.flowName,
           header: this.flowLabel,
           flowModal: true,
           showHeader: this.showHeader,
           showFooter: this.showFooter,
           inputVariables: this.inputVariables,
           flowFinish: this.flowFinish,
           desription: this.flowDescription,
           disableClose: this.disableClose,
           recordId: this.recordId
       });
   }
}

Modal LWC markup:
<template>
   <lightning-modal-header label={header}></lightning-modal-header>
   <lightning-modal-body>
       <template lwc:if={flowModal}>
           <div class="slds-is-relative">
               <lightning-flow 
                   flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
                   onstatuschange={handleStatusChange} 
                   flow-api-name={flowName}
                   flow-finish-behavior={flowFinish}
               >
               </lightning-flow>
           </div>
       </template>
   </lightning-modal-body>
   <template lwc:if={showFooter}>
       <lightning-modal-footer>
           <lightning-button label="Close" onclick={handleClose}></lightning-button>
       </lightning-modal-footer>
   </template>
</template>

Modal LWC js:
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

export default class stage_Change_Modal extends LightningModal {

   /* FLOW PROPERTIES */
   @api recordId;
   @api header;
   @api flowName;
   @api flowModal = false;
   @api showFooter = false;
   @api showHeader = false;
   @api flowFinish = 'NONE';
   @api inputVariables;


   handleStatusChange(event) {
       if(event.detail.status === 'FINISHED'){
           this.close('flow finished: '+this.flowName);     

           this.dispatchEvent(
               new ShowToastEvent({
                 title: "Success",
                 message: "Stage Changed Successfully.",
                 variant: "success",
            })
           );
 
       }
   }

   handleClose(){
     this.close('modal is closed');
    }

}


you can use the notifyRecordUpdateAvailable(recordIds)
Quote from the documentation:

Informs Lightning Data Service that record data has changed so that Lightning Data Service can take the appropriate actions to keep wire adapters updated with the latest record data. Call this function to notify Lightning Data Service that a record has changed outside its mechanisms, such as via imperative Apex or by calling User Interface API via a third-party framework.

In your LWC, when the event.detail.status === 'FINISHED'.
like this:
import {notifyRecordUpdateAvailable } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


   async handleStatusChange(event) {
       if(event.detail.status === 'FINISHED'){
           this.close('flow finished: '+this.flowName);     
           await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
           this.dispatchEvent(
               new ShowToastEvent({
                 title: "Success",
                 message: "Stage Changed Successfully.",
                 variant: "success",
            })
           );

 
       }
   }

If you would like to know more about this, you can refer to the
documentation hyperlinked.
